# "to be to" to express expected/anticipated action to take place

Tags: sentence-construction

I am trying to think of proper language to express an action a user of an appliance is entitled to expect and otherwise is considered a malfunction. For instance, is it correct to write "Once the handle is pulled, the door **is to** open" like in a User Manual for a door, if there is such a thing as a door manual? In my mother tongue, I use an equivalent of "must", which is a polysemantic word whose exact meaning you figure out through its context and is not an option in the one I am dealing with.

Comment: "the door opens" or "the door must open", but the first one is better if I have to choose.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Of the two options, I would stick to the former, too, if not for the text in the source language that makes one assume there are circumstances when the door might not open due to a hinge failure, among other reasons. My cautious guess is that "ought to" should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., what is idiomatic is

> When the handle is pulled, the door will open

This is a prediction, a statement about the future that reflects certainty or great confidence.

> When the handle is pulled, the door should open.

This reflects expectation. It tends to imply a minor degree of doubt.

In a manual, the first probably should be used. “Ought to” is a synonym of “should” but may indicate a greater degree of doubt.

Comment: Thank you! "Should" should work out fine. Actually, obvious solution I should have seen right away, which I haven't.

Comment: Modal verbs are tricky even for native speakers.